# DAX measure. How to compute performance divide target

Tags: powerbi, dax

How would you compute %Achv for each year when you have different  targets for each year and of course different performance. Keep in mind %Achv=Performance/Target
==>> %Achv yr1=Performance yr1/ Target yr1
Whereby the Time slicer will be in control. That is If I pick year, it shows %Achv for year 1 and so on

Answer (score 0):

the answer depends on your model. What kind of data model are you using? If your model is not weirdly complex, it shouldn't be too hard. Here is an extremely simplified solution with examples:

Model could be something like this:
[image: mData model]

Tables for calender, sales and targets.

The sales and targets tables have the values with dates.
[image: sales and targets tables]

With a simple model like this, we can achieve the wanted results with these very simple measures:

```
Sum Sales = SUM(Sales[Sales])
Sum Targets = SUM(Targets[Target])
%Achv = [Sum Sales]/[Sum Targets]
```

[image: measures in action]

Comment: Thanks. This is beautiful.

Comment: Thanks, this is beautiful. I have such a simple model but my targets are in years and performance in months for each year. So I need a DAX that will divide targets by 12 for each year. Then this can be used to compute %Achv monthly since I need to visualize my data with months running x axis. see the visual I need though this data yor 1 year alone

Comment: Okay, the most simple thing to try could be, how about a calculated column for target table?
 
`AvgTarget per month = Targets[Target]/12`

That would give you target to use for measures